# How to call a stored procedure in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 7

I want to call a stored procedure in Crystal Report.

How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the stored procedure into your report; like you would add a table.

Add the parameters the stored procedure needs to run; as parameters **with exactly the same name they have on the stored procedure.**

So if the SP had two parameters, @PARAM1 and @PARAM2 you would need these same paramaters (name, type etc) in your report.

Crystal will allow you to use the SP returned fields like any normal table's fields.

Comment: My Store Procedure has output param cursor for example: Procedure Buscar ( IN_TEST IN NUMBER, OUT_CURSOR OUT m_refcur) IS ...  How I call from CR?