# How to execute stored procedure parameter in crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I am use crystal report - 11
I want execute stored procedure with parameter using `add command`.
I am tried below code-

```
exec sf02.gen_statement_data('MS0001','1-Nov-2013','15-Nov-2013')
```

but it fetch error invalid SQL statement.
so please give me a solution for that.

Comment: can you please let me know what is sf02?

Comment: sf02 is schema name and gen_statement_data is procedure name.

Comment: please refer [How to call Stored Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8295041/3110262)

Comment: I don't want to add procedure like add table.I want call procedure using 'Add Command'.

Comment: please take a look to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/561000/3110262) hope it will be helpful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call Stored Procedure from crystal report,

Set data source of report to Stored Procedure (DataBase Expert Wizard). That procedure must met thses requirement

1- You must create a package that defines the REF CURSOR (type of field that will be retrieved).

2- The procedure must have a parameter that is a REF CURSOR type. This is because CR uses this parameter to access and define the result set that the stored procedure returns.

3- The REF CURSOR parameter must be defined as IN OUT (read/write mode).

4- Parameters can only be input (IN) parameters. CR is not designed to work with OUT parameters.

5- The REF CURSOR variable must be opened and assigned its query within the procedure.

6- The stored procedure can only return one record set. The structure of this record set must not change, based on parameters.

7- The stored procedure cannot call another stored procedure.

Comment: hi A B, when prompted  'Add Command To Report', how should I put in my code? Is it CALL schema1.sp_process_1({?p_param1}) ? I have an OUT Sys_RefCursor, should I put that in too?